# Is there a way to avoid pressing enter when maunually inputting data? c++

Tags: c++, cin, enter

Here is my situation: I wrote a quick and dirty program to scan serial numbers off of a large number of items and store the data into a file. Unfortunately the real world process goes: scan, hit enter, scan again.

My question is can I get it to where I can avoid hitting enter repeatedly.

Sample input:

> 123YLR12

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int i=0;
string death;//was showing a third party that anything can be declared a variable.
int main()
{
 ofstream filevariable;
 filevariable.open ("SavedDataFile", ofstream::app);
 while (i==0) //infinite loop but it's fine i kill it with CTRL+C
 {
  cin>>death;
  cout<<endl;
  filevariable << death << endl;
 }
}
```

Since it's not a single character but a series of letters and numbers pulled off a scanner i can't use `_getch()` and I can't seem to find any sort of reference to how to avoid pressing enter.

Platform:

> Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit.

Comment: Have you thought about passing your input in as a command line argument or input file?

Comment: The scanner can't be set to send enter after scanning? That's what I've always done.

Comment: There's no portable way to do that in c++. Try to access your keyboard input at low level as appropriate with your operating system.

Comment: We used to pass Enter automatically.. but I totally forgot how. It is doable so keep searching

Comment: _@Salvadorjer_ IMHO going with [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) would be the most portable solution.

Comment: Also "it's fine because I use Ctrl-C" is not fine. That interrupts your program, which does not guarantee the output file gets flushed correctly. Instead, exit on EOF.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I'm looking into ncurses now. As for the duplicate thread, the other ones are only looking for a single character and can use specific functions for that whereas i have a series (of varying size depending on the model) of characters as the input. And for Zastai :) i'm modifying it with an end condition to the loop followed by a return 0.